# Magento - Mage::getModel not working on Linux server

Tags: magento, module

I'm struggling with an issue for which I can't find an explanation. I have two development environments that I use for my projects. I created a simple module for Magento and I tested it on one environment. After overcoming all Magento's complications, the module works as expected. This is on XAMPP.

I then copied the module to the development Linux environment, on a hosted server, and it crashes miserably. I did some debugging, and I found out that a call to Mage::getModel() returns *bool(false)* instead of the instance of the Model I requested.

I double checked all files and directories, and they match. Database is not involved (not from my side, at least, I don't need tables) and both environments have only me as a User, with Admin permissions.

Any suggestion on where should I start looking is welcome, thanks.

**Added on 2012/07/09**
Model contains a class named `Diego_ClientCustomModule_Model_ExternalUserData`, which is invoked with `$model = Mage::getModel('clientcustommodule/externaluserdata');`. Model file resides in `Diego_ClientCustomModule\code\local\Diego\ClientCustomModule\Model\`. The curious thing is:

- If model file is named `Externaluserdata.php`, it works.
- If model file is named `ExternalUserData.php` (i.e. it matches the class name), it doesn't work.

I'm aware of case sensitivity stuff etc, but, if the alias is all lower-case, how comes it can load a file having the first letter capitalized?

**Configuration file**
    
    
      
        
          0.1.0
            
      
      
        
          
            Diego_ClientCustomModule_Helper
          
        
        
          
            Diego_ClientCustomModule_Model
          
        
        
          
            Diego_ClientCustomModule_Block
          
        
      
      
        
          
            standard
            
              Diego_ClientCustomModule
              ClientCustomModule

Comment: I edited out the snark — that sort of thing tends to discourage people from answering.  What model are you trying to instantiate?

Comment: Leaving aside that it wasn't just snarking, the model is my own custom one.

Comment: If you provide that name of the class alias you were using, as well as the class itself, it can help people track down your problem or rule out certain things.  It increases the chances someone will be able to help.

Comment: @AlanStorm Thanks, I solved the issue. However, out of curiosity, what do you mean with "class alias"? As I wrote in my answer, the issue was related to some obscure issue with the capitalization of the file name, which I still don't understand.

Comment: Well, it's not that obscure a thing in software development circles.  Learning to accept how Magento does things is key to making it work. The string in the getModel, getBlock, and helper methods is a class alias.  Mage::getModel('catalog/product').  The string catalog/product is a class alias. If you'd included that plus your <code>config.xml</code> we would have known the class you were trying to instantiate, and could have told you where the files needed to go/be named (indirectly guiding us towards the capitalization.

Comment: @AlanStorm Sorry for having been unclear, I'm aware of the various issues about loaders, file names and idiosyncrasies of multiple platforms, I've been in Development for many years. The thing I really couldn't figure out is why a file is loaded only if it has the first letter capitalized, and not the others, while the rest of the files (controller, design, blocks) are processed if their name is CamelCase. Anyway, I'm attaching the config file for your review and updating the question. Although the issue is solved, it's a solution "by coincidence", I'd like to know more. Thanks.

Comment: The Varien_Autoloader is loaded before the Mage class, so Mage::log can't be used to log from there.  Try logging with something like file_put_contents('/tmp/autoload.log',"$classFile\n",FILE_APPEND); As for the CamelCase problem.  Magento gets your class alias: clientcustommodule/externaluserdata.  It uses "clientcustommodule" to lookup a base class name from your config.xml (Diego_ClientCustomModule_Model_)  Then it appends "externaluserdata" to create the final class name (Diego_ClientCustomModule_Model_Externaluserdata ).  How does it know which other letters to capitalize?

Comment: A-ha! Then it **does** capitalize one letter, it's to build the class name! That's what I couldn't figure out. I really couldn't see the reason for behind the effort to capitalize one letter, while they could have simply used the whole name lowercase. Anyway, the class itself is in CamelCase (Diego_ClientCustomModule_Model_ExternalUserData), and it's loaded properly if the **file name** has just the first letter capitalized. That's something odd, as I thought class names were case sensitive too.

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip about the Autoloader. Many frameworks I used tend to initialize the logger as the very first thing, so that it's available immediately. Personally, when an Autoloader is involved, I think this is even more important, as the framework "does things by itself" and logging is vital to follow what's going on. From my perspective, not having Mage::log() available in that phase is a mistake, but I guess there was a reason for this.

Comment: Max respect for Alan Storm!! but agree with Diego, this was working fine on wamp, move to server, it no go, rename all model files to lower case, nek min BOOM it working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Snarking about the framework for which you are asking for help may not be the best strategy for receiving help.

Your issue is likely one of cache (remove var/cache folder to check) or one of improper casing. Note that the first letter of each directory and filename for files loaded by the autoloader (blocks, models, and helpers).

Comment: Thanks, but cache is disabled and I cleaned so many times it's now shiny. Cache folder is empty. What I'm trying to figure out now is where Magento logs its actions, to see if it goes even close to the model. I tried to put a logging action (Mage::log) in the Autoloader, but that single line crashes the whole system.

Answer (score 3):

It seems I have found the root cause of the issue, although I can't figure out what kind of logic has been implemented to make it happen.

Model's file name was ***UserCustomModule.php***, which reflected the class name ***UserCustomModule***. That made sense, and worked wonderfully in XAMPP. Once I installed the same module on a Linux box, Magento silently ignored the file and, as previously stated, there's been no way to track down Magento's actions.

Following benmark suggestion, I went through all the files again to check the casing, and everything seemed to match. I then made something, in my opinion, completely stupid, and I renamed the Model file to ***Usercustommodule.php***, leaving the class name untouched (after all, PHP should behave the same on both platforms, unlike the file system). Magically, the module now works! The file name looks cr*p, but it works.

This solved the problem, yet it raises more questions:

- For what reason Magento has troubles loading a file with a CamelCase name? If it's Autoloading, it should simply find a file and load it. After all, it loads the Controller, the Block and everything else, and they are **all** in CamelCase.
- Is it written anywhere that one or more files must have only the first letter capitalized? I got enough surprises already, I'd like to avoid new ones, if possible.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: As I answered, improper casing. Welcome to case-sensitive filesystems and autoloaders. The autoloader class method used by Magento ([`Varien_Autoload::autoload()`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.1/lib/Varien/Autoload.php#L81)) is invoked to locate the classnames you are specifying, and those names are built by replacing _ with a space, running `ucwords()` on the name "sentence", replacing spaces with the OS directory separator, adding ".php", and then `include()`ing the file. FWIW, if this all seems frivolous, it's (1) an OS issue and (2) a Zend Framework convention.

Comment: The issue is not just a matter of case sensitivity. The file follows precisely Zend/Magento's standards, with underscore and everything, but the file is not autoloaded if it contains any capital letters, except for the first one. When file name matched the class name, the autoloader ignored it. Now that they don't match, the autoloader loads it. So the rule seems to be "just the first letter can by capitalized" , which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: As an additional note, I'd like to point out that I found the autoloader before posting on SO, but, when I tried to add some logging into it, all I got was a crash of the system. A simple Mage::log('message') prevented the home page from opening and returned dozens of "class Mage-whatever not found" (or something like that) in the PHP error log. Magento seems very delicate to me (one of the reasons why I never use the Zend framework).

Comment: I'm working on a linux box as well, and I think the problem is actually in your coding: `$model = Mage::getModel('clientcustommodule/externaluserdata');` should be `$model = Mage::getModel('clientcustommodule/externalUserData');` - that lets your filename be ExternalUserData.php